# Error when finishing an application with a savepoint

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to finish some applications that use RocksDB state backend in the incremental mode and I want to keep a savepoint to start use in the next execution. Whenever I try do finish, this error shows.

[image]

Errors:

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: 
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: 
org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointException: Checkpoint Coordinator is suspending.
```

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.SerializedThrowable: 
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: 
org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointException: Checkpoint Coordinator is suspending.
```

That's the way I try to create this savepoint:

```
flink stop -t yarn-per-job -Dyarn.application.id=application_1619785296629_0002 6c1d387d0a863936e55e3c89cd31b72d -p s3://my-bucket/flink/savepoints/
```

If this is a timeout issue, what is the right way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue opended.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-21028.

The version I use has this problem (1.11.2).